# Android camera exception (com.android.camera.action.CROP intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

I have a question about crop functionality in android. i used samsung gio for debugging and progect and image cropping are working  on this device well. but when i tried to run this project on Sony Experia S (Android version 4.0.4) and Prestigio multipad (Tablet | Android version is 4.0.3) I'm throwed an exception in com.camera.android(standard camera android app, error details added below). So camera is started and I'm making photo,and after clicking on OK button the camera app is falling and throwing me an error. Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString()); 
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 4);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
intent.putExtra("scale", false);
getOutputMediaFile(PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

try {
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.toString();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity 
    {com.newvision.firstteacher/com.newvision.firstteacher.AlphabetConstructorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at com.newvision.firstteacher.AlphabetConstructorActivity.onActivityResult(AlphabetConstructorActivity.java:270)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
06-07 18:24:08.602: E/AndroidRuntime(18063):    ... 11 more
```

What I have to do to solve this problem with exception in camera app? Or may be I'm pass some wrong parameters with intent? 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "falls and throw me an error" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "error".

Comment: @CommonsWare Already edited

Comment: And, when you examined line 270 of `AlphabetConstructorActivity.java`, in your `onActivityResult()` method, what did you learn?

Comment: @CommonsWare in onActivityResult() data = null, and when I try "Bundle extras = data.getExtras();" null pointer exception is appears, because  Gallery app throwing exception and returns null to my method.

Comment: "because Gallery app throwing exception" -- please post the Gallery app's stack trace, then. Bear in mind that you should not be relying on `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to do cropping, anyway: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html